# Vb.net Could not save, locked by another user

Tags: vb.net

I am having the problem that about when i try to update a picture, and i click save the error message said that "could not save, locked by another user. where error i did? Sometimes I could update, but sometimes not, why?
And I realize that I have to open Access file and close it then will work.
The error line is cmd.ExecuteNonQuery().

```
    Dim con = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source =..\room.accdb")

    Dim ms As New MemoryStream
    Dim arrimg As Byte()
    Me.PictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
    arrimg = ms.GetBuffer()
    ms.Read(arrimg, 0, ms.Length)

    Dim sql As String = "UPDATE Userss SET profilepicture =@profilepicture WHERE studentid=" & Form1.txtStuID.Text & ";"
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    con.open()
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, con)
    Dim photo As OleDbParameter = New OleDbParameter("@profilepicture", SqlDbType.Image)
    photo.Value = arrimg
    cmd.Parameters.Add(photo)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MessageBox.Show("Profile picture saved.")
    con.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'locked by another user' is a vague message by MS Access since it can be due to a couple of different reasons. It's not to be confused by a specific reason (such as always meaning a table lock). It can be that or it can be the *.ldb file itself or it can be form/table design or even permissions related. However, in your scenario, you are getting it since you have opened the db on MS Access as you mentioned. Opening the db / tables, usually put a lock on the tables.

When you open a record or the form (or table structure) is not designed optimally or someone opens the mdb/accdb who doesn't have both read and write permissions to the folder and file. This error has to do with the *.ldb file associated with the *.mdb/accdb file which is actually what is 'locking' and causing the error.

Some options can be considered, like;

- using a `NO LOCK` in your update statement, but that might not be the best one.
- make sure all your connections are well disposed after use.
- use `using` blocks for your objects that implement `IDisposable`.
- you can also read a bit about [DEADLOCKS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa892828.aspx), it might help avoid locks

Comment: thank you for your reply, I have tried "No lock" in my database, and disposed connection is that means like " con.disposed" before con.close?

Comment: It work for some few times, but a few more times I changed, will faced the same error. I have added 
cmd.Dispose()

        con.Close()
        con.Dispose()
every last line of the coding

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
    Dim arrimg As Byte()
    Using ms As New MemoryStream
        Me.PictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
        arrimg = ms.GetBuffer()
        ms.Read(arrimg, 0, ms.Length)
    End Using

    Using con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source =..\room.accdb")
        con.Open()
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("UPDATE Userss SET profilepicture = @profilepicture WHERE studentid = @studentId;", con)
            Dim studentID As New OleDbParameter("@studentId", Form1.txtStuID.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.Add(studentID)
            Dim photo As New OleDbParameter("@profilepicture", SqlDbType.Image)
            photo.Value = arrimg
            cmd.Parameters.Add(photo)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MessageBox.Show("Profile picture saved.")
        End Using
        con.Close()
    End Using
```

From the code i can see you mix presentation and data access logic, you should probably limit each of your feature to DAL methods so it's easier to find where your DB connection stay open.

With `Using` like this you can easily avoid to manually dispose the objects and you can be sure the connection will be closed even with exceptions.

Always use parameters and check for disposable object (like `MemoryStream`).